# Materialize grid do 5 columns

Tags: html, css, frameworks, materialize

I have div s12, how I can do in Materialize 5 columns?

My code:

```
<div class="col s12">
  <div class="col s12 l2"></div>
  <div class="col s12 l2"></div>
  <div class="col s12 l4"></div>
  <div class="col s12 l2"></div>
  <div class="col s12 l2"></div>
</div>
```

Please help do 5 same columns. 12/5 not entirely share.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Materialize 5 Column Responsive Layout

The below is compatible with Materialize 0.98.1 and above as it uses the newly introduced `xl` media breakpoint.

Add the following CSS to your global stylesheet, The above CSS is compatible with other Materialize `.col` classes too. For example, if you want 5 equal columns on medium and above, and half width columns on small and below, use the following:

```css
.s5ths,
.m5ths,
.l5ths,
.xl5ths {
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.row .col.s5ths {
  width: 20%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .row .col.m5ths {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .row .col.l5ths {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .row .col.xl5ths {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m5ths s6">Column 1</div>
      <div class="col m5ths s6">Column 2</div>
      <div class="col m5ths s6">Column 3</div>
      <div class="col m5ths s6">Column 4</div>
      <div class="col m5ths s6">Column 5</div>
    </div>
```

**[Here is a working example of the above](https://jsfiddle.net/2ppdp6n1/)**. Resize the window to see it in action.

---

If you're using SASS in your project, I highly recommend using the [SASS media queries](http://materializecss.com/sass.html) that Materialize provides.

Comment: I've put this into a Codepen demo for anyone that's interested: https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/LYYmNMK

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to make a common custom class and inherit properties from `materialize` of their `s1, s2...` elements as per your requirements as:

### Code Snippet

```css
.grid-example {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 7px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-col {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col custom-col grid-example">1</div>
  <div class="col custom-col grid-example">2</div>
  <div class="col custom-col grid-example">3</div>
  <div class="col custom-col grid-example">4</div>
  <div class="col custom-col grid-example">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not adaptive for mibiles and other devices

Comment: @BlogSER yep, it won't for that you have to write your own *CSS* using `media queries` for `.custom-col`, i.e. why I have mentioned **custom class**

Comment: and how i can do adaptive this columns?

Comment: Learn form the *materialize*, study how they have done the same with their classes, learn about `media queries` how to use them for your *CSS*, these will surely help you a lot.